# Ember-data hasMany relationship not working (JSONAPIAdapter)

Tags: ember-data

I'm using Ember-Data v.1.13.9 with Ember-CLI v.1.13.8. I'm using the JSONAPIAdapter adapter.

I have a problem with a hasMany relationship. I can see from the Ember inspector that both the main record and the related record are being loaded into the store. However, the relationship doesn't seem to be there since I cannot access the related records details in my template.

**models/invoice.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend(
{
    invNum          : DS.attr('string'),
    created         : DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }}),
    clientId        : DS.attr('number'),
    userId          : DS.attr('number'),
    details         : DS.hasMany('invoice-detail', {async : true}),
});
```

**models/invoice-detail.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend(
{
    invoice     : DS.belongsTo('invoice', {async : true}),
    detail      : DS.attr('string'),
    amount      : DS.attr('number'),
    vat         : DS.attr('number'),
});
```

**my JSON data: (URL: /accounts/invoices/1)**

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "inv-num": "A0011000001",
      "created": "November, 01 2000 00:00:00",
      "user-id": 2,
      "client-id": 14,
      "relationships": {
        "details": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "invoice-detail"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "invoice"
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "amount": 3000,
        "detail": "Stage 1 delivery of 3Com Reseller Locator to\r\nFoundation Network LTD",
        "vat": 525
      },
      "type": "invoice-detail"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried accessing the details related array directly:

```
{{#each model.details as |detail index|}}
    {{index}} : {{detail.detail}} &pound;{{detail.amount}} (&pound;{{detail.vat}} vat)
{{/each}}
```

And by using a controller: **invoice/controller.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    invoiceDetails : function()
    {
        var invoice = this.get("model");
        var details = invoice.get("details");

        Ember.Logger.log("invoiceDetails",invoice,details);

        return details;
    }.property('model.details'),

});
```

and

```
{{#each invoiceDetails as |detail index|}}
    {{index}} : {{detail.detail}} &pound;{{detail.amount}} (&pound;{{detail.vat}} vat)
{{/each}}
```

Neither is providing me with the data that I require.

What am I doing wrong?

A second related issue I am having is that I can't get it to reload data from the server. the {reload:true} makes no difference. Looking at the network traffic I can see that no call to the server is made for second and subsequent visits to this route.

**invoice/route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('invoice', params.id, { reload: true });
  }
})
```

What I actually want to do here is have one route which retrieves a list of invoices (without the details part - so it's quick to retrieve since I do not need the details on the list page). Then, when I drill down to a specific invoice, make a call to the server to get the full details for that invoice. My plan was to use the shouldReloadRecord function to check if I have details attached to this record or not. If so, use the copy from the store, if not, go to the server and then overwrite the limited "list" record I got initially. As a stepping stone in that direction I figured that just setting {reload:true} in the route would force all requests to go back to the server.

I guess I've misunderstood something somewhere...?

Comment: Try moving `relationships` outside of the "attributes" layer of your JSON response. So instead of `data.attributes.relationships` you have `data.relationships`

Comment: Thanks. I've been staring at that all night! Sometime you just need another pair of eyes! I'd check your answer as the correct one, but you've onyl added a comment....

Comment: I still can't work out why it does not reload the whole invoice record though? When I get the list I am not getting any relationships (I don't need them for the list page). When I go into my detail page I want to force Ember to go back to the server to get the entire invoice record, rather than use the one in in the store which probably doesn't have the details attached. I've managed it with my controller which check if details exists and if not, does a query to get invoice-details. It works, but doesn't seem to be the right way to do it to me...?